# Question about the exercise: Prove that $\prod A_{i}$ may be identified with the set of all choice functions for $h$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For the following question:

> $(1):$ A cartesian product of the family $(A_i|i\in I)$ of sets is the set
> $$\prod_{i\in I}A_i=\{f|f:I\rightarrow\cup_{i\in I}A_i \text{with } f(i)\in A_i \text{ for each } i\in I\}$$
> together with the projections $\pi_{j}:\prod_{i\in I}A_i\rightarrow A_j,$ $f\mapsto f(j)$
>
> In the context of $(1)$, let $h:\coprod A_{i}\rightarrow I$ be defined by $h(a,i)=i$.  **Prove** that $\prod A_{i}$ may be identified with the set of all choice functions for $h$ in the sense of the following exercise:
>
> Exercises: Prove that for every function $f:A\rightarrow B$ with $A$ non-empty, there exists a 'choice function' $g:B\rightarrow A$ such that $f\circ g \circ f=f$
>
> Note: $\prod_{i\in I}A_i$ denotes the cartesian product of sets $A_i$ and $\coprod_{i\in I}A_i$ denotes the coproduct of sets $A_i$.

Can someone explain what the question is asking.  Specifically, I don't understand the phrase "...that $\prod A_{i}$ may be identified with the set of all choice functions for $h$...".
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley I thought I made a mistake myself for giving it the tagged elementary set theory.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley kk, I revised the tagging.  THank you for letting me know.

Comment: Have you done the exercise finding $g : B \to A$?

Comment: @PaulFrost The function  for the quoted exercise is defined as $()=$ if $\in ()$ else, $()=′$ if $\in  \setminus ()$

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking you to show that there is a canonical bijection between $\prod_{i\in I}A_i$ and the set $C$ of all choice functions for the "indexing projection" $\coprod_{i\in I}A_i\to I$ in the sense defined.

Unfortunately the question is not quite right as stated because if $I\ne\emptyset$, you need to assume that $A_i\ne\emptyset$ for all $i\in I$, otherwise it's possible that $\prod_{i\in I}A_i=\emptyset$ while there exists a choice function for the indexing projection in the sense defined.

Assuming that $A_i\ne\emptyset$ for all $i\in I$, define $F:\prod_{i\in I}A_i\to C$ by $F(f)(i)=(f(i),i)$ for all $i\in I$, and define $G:C\to\prod_{i\in I}A_i$ by $G(g)(i)=p(g(i))$ for all $i\in I$ where $p:\coprod_{i\in I}A_i\to\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ is defined by $p(a,i)=a$. Then it is easy to verify that $F$ and $G$ are inverses.

Comment: Do you mean $p(a,i)=i$?  Also how did you end up with the mapping $p:\coprod_{i\in I}A_i\to\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ for $p$. I mean should $\coprod_{i\in I}A_i$ go to $I$ instead of $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$?

Comment: @Seth No, I meant what I wrote.

Comment: ok ok.  Can I ask why is $h$ consider to be a "choice function".  Since the question included the quoted exercise and also the cartesian product version of the choice function.  I am not sure in which case $h$ is being referred to.

Comment: the text I got the question from is Arrows, Structures and Functors, the categorical imperative.  I am in the first chapter and the author don't go into details at all about the finer details of what choice functions other than telling the readers what the definition for them are suppose to be.  He does talk a lot more about products and coproducts.

Comment: @Seth The function $h$ is *not* considered to be a choice function, it is sometimes called an indexing projection and is a different representation of the indexed family $(A_i)_{i\in I}$. I suggest you take a simple, concrete example like $I=\{1,2\}$ with two sets $A_1$ and $A_2$ and work through all the definitions carefully to see what they mean.

Comment: can I ask you with you answer that $g(i)=(f(i),i)=(a,i)$, is that correct?  Also, in the context of your solution, where does $h:\coprod A_{i}\rightarrow I$ fit in in the commutative diagram.  With your suggestions for the case of $I=\{1,2\}$, we have $\prod_{i=1,2 }A_i=A_i\times A_2$ and $A_i \coprod A_2$ with $\prod_{i=1,2 }A_i=A_i\times A_2=\{g|g:I\rightarrow \cup_{i=1,2}A_i\}=\{g(1), g(2)\}$ and $(a,1)\in A_1$ and $(a,2)\in A_2$. Also, $F(f)(1)=(f(1),1)$, $F(f)(2)=(f(2),2)$...

Comment: ..$G(g)(2)=p(g(2))$ with $p(a,1)=a$ and $p(a,2)=a$. Now $h:A_i \coprod A_2\rightarrow \{1,2\}$ is defined by $h(a,i)=i$, for $i=1,2$. I am guessing here that $(a,i)=(f(i),i)$ and $g(i)=(g\circ h)(a,i)$ where $f(i)=a$ for $i=1,2$. Then we have $F(f)(i)=(f(i),i)$, and $[G\circ F](f)(i)=[G\circ F(f)](i)=(p\circ g)(i)=p(g(i))=p(f(i),i)=f(i)$ and $(F\circ [G\circ F])(f)(i)=F\circ ([G\circ F(f)])(i))=F(f)(i)=(f(i),i).$  Hence $F\circ G \circ F=F$.  Flushing out the details of your mappings, I get the following: (not sure if I got all

Comment: the name of the mapping and the labeling of the codomains for the explicit mapping all correct)  $I\xrightarrow{\prod_{i\in I}{A_i}} \cup_{i\in I}A_i$ defined by $ i\mapsto f=(f(i))_{i\in I},$  **(1)** 
$\prod_{i\in I}{A_i}\xrightarrow{{\pi}_j\circ f} A_j$ defined by ${\pi}_j(f) \mapsto f(j),$ **(2)**
$A_j\xrightarrow{p_i} \coprod_{i\in I}{A_i}$ defined by $f(j) \mapsto (f(j),j),$ **(3)** $\coprod_{i\in I}{A_i}\xrightarrow{h} I$ defined by $(a,i) \mapsto i,$ **(4)**

Comment: $\coprod_{i\in I}{A_i}\xrightarrow{h} I\xrightarrow{f} \cup_{i\in I}A_i$ defined by $(a,i) \mapsto i\mapsto a$,  **(5)**  and letting $a=f(i),$ we have $(f(i),i) \mapsto i\mapsto f(i).$  **(6)**  Other than my question about the map $h$ relating to $C$,is my understanding of what you are trying to say correct in the case of your concrete suggestion?

Comment: @Seth you have many confusions and misunderstandings here, too many for me to address. My general advice is to maybe try working through a simpler book (preferably with an instructor) on introduction to proofs, to master the basic notation and language of sets and functions, before continuing with this material. Otherwise it's like trying to understand a novel in a foreign language you haven't learned. Good luck.

Comment: I am going through Conceptual Mathematics: A First Introduction to Categories by Stephen Schanuel and William Lawvere concurrently with Arrows Structures and Functors by Ernest G. Manes and Michael A. Arbib by  myself. I think there is some subtlety in notations for the concept of coproduct that I am not seeing here from just learning from a text.  I spoken to grad students who have brief exposure to category theory in the grad algebra courses.  When I showed them the book and the exercises from the book, they told me they never go through the category material in depth.

Comment: I really appreciate you trying to help me and with your many detailed write ups of the solutions.