# Is this the correct way to generalize the description for the disjoint union of an indexed family of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The definition for the disjoint union of two sets are as follow:

> Given any pairs $A_1$ and $A_2$ of sets (which may possibly have elements in common) we form the sets $A_1\times \{1\}=\{(a_1,1)|a_1\in A_1\}$ and $A_2\times \{2\}=\{(a_2,2)|a_2\in A_2\}$ which are guaranteed to be disjoint, since whenever $(a,k)=(a',k')$, $k=k'$, so that $A_1\times \{1\}\cap A_2\times \{2\}=\emptyset.$  We then let $A_1 + A_2$ be the union $A_1\times \{1\}\cup A_2\times \{2\}$ - we call it the disjoint union of $A_1$ and $A_2$ because we ensured that the two sets were disjoint before uniting them - and define the maps
>
> $${in}_k :A_k \rightarrow A_1+A_2 :a\mapsto (a,k) \text{ for } k=1,2$$
>
> Along with $q_1:A_1 \rightarrow C$ and $q_2:A_2\rightarrow C$, there exists a unique map $q$ such that $q:A_1+A_2\dashrightarrow C$, defined as $q(a_k, k)=q_k(a_k)$.

[image]

If I want to generalize the above definition for a disjoint union of an indexed family of sets.
**Does it go as follow:**

Suppose we have an indexed family of sets $(A_i|i\in I)$, we form the family of sets  $A_i \times \{i\}=\{(a_i,i)|a_i\in A_i, \wedge  i\in I\}$.  For any pair of sets and each of their respective elements, $(a_i,i)=(a_j,j)$, $i=j,$ so that $A_i\times \{i\}\cap A_j\times \{j\}=\emptyset.$
We let $A_1 + A_2 + \cdots + A_i$ to denote the disjoint union of $A_1 \times \{1\} \cup A_2 \times \{2\} \cup \cdots \cup A_i \times \{i\}.$
We define the family of maps:
${in}_i :A_i \rightarrow A_1 + A_2+ \cdots + A_k :a_i\mapsto (a_i,i) \text{ for } i=1,2,\ldots k$, along with another family of maps:  $q_i:A_i\rightarrow C$, $i=1,2,\ldots k.$  There exists a unique map $q$ such that $q:A_1 + A_2+ \cdots + A_k\dashrightarrow C,$ with $q_k=q\circ {in}_k$ and the relation between the maps $q$ and $q_k$ is given by the following identity relation $q(a_k, k)=q_k(a_k)$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley i answered in my other post about separating the two questions into individual separate posts.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley I am not sure the notion of coproduct is related to the disjoint union.  I looked up on wikipedia, it discussed disjoint union without referencing to coproduct.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley I am trying to respect the recommended guidelines on how to ask good questions and also not to spam the forum with questions that can be lumped together into a single post.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley thank you.

Comment: "I looked up on wikipedia, it discussed disjoint union without referencing to coproduct." From [Disjoint union - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union): "In terms of category theory, the disjoint union is the coproduct of the category of sets." In view of the confusion I caused earlier, I hesitate to recommend an answer of mine, but you might get *something* from it (other than just a headache!): [Is there a coproduct in $\mathsf{Set}$ that is $\textit{not}$ the disjoint union?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4339605) (See particularly the quotation from an earlier answer.)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley if you have a free moment, can I ask you to take a look at this question I posted awhile ago today. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4580054/question-about-the-exercise-prove-that-prod-a-i-may-be-identified-with-the?noredirect=1#comment9641883_4580054
I am having a hard time trying to figure out what the question is asking.  Also, I am not sure how to relate the product back to the coproduct.  I have done the quoted exercise within the question.  Thank you.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley by the way, i separated disjoint union from coproduct, because I am currently learning abstract algebra on my own.  Along the way, I came across the notion of "disjoint union" independent of the context of the coproduct, but whenever i did encountered "coproduct", "disjoint union" seem to be joint to it from the hips.  I got the impression that the notions are conceptually distinct.  I think people in category theory might see them as intrinsically linked. I got the question from a introductory text on category theory.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley But the product and the coproduct business are both before the notion of category are properly introduced.  I have a feeling that I will see these concepts again in algebra without reference to category theory like in the context of modules.  Hence I treated them as distinct for the purpose of asking questions on here.